# Yii2 calculation result difference of two columns

Tags: yii2, difference, subtraction

I can't find a solution related to a problem that I thought was easier to solve. I have two columns with numeric values ​​INT (5) and in a third I should get the result of the difference for each single row of course.

I took a cue from the addition solution on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49382821/yii2-gridview-sort-sum-of-values-of-two-columns) but returns in (no value) for each row.

In model Sistop.php:

```
public function getDiff()
{
    $this->diff = 0;

    if (is_numeric($this->qdsistop) && is_numeric($this->qusistop)) {
        $this->diff = $this->qdsistop - $this->qusistop;
    }

    return $this->diff;
}
```

In SistopSearch.php

```
class SistopSearch extends Sistop
{

    public function attributes()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['diff']);
    }

......

   public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Sistop::find()->select('*, (`qdsistop` - `qusistop`) AS `diff`');
        // add conditions that should always apply here
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        // enable sorting for the related columns
        $dataProvider->sort->attributes['diff'] = [
            'asc' => ['diff' => SORT_ASC],
            'desc' => ['diff' => SORT_DESC],
        ];


.....
        if (is_numeric($this->diff)) {
            $query->having([
                'diff' => $this->diff,
            ]);
        }
```

The result is same: (no value) for each row.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to display on grid (ex kartik grid), just add one custom column and give it value option = col1-col2

Answer (score 0):

Use `addSelect` with array input arguments:

```
$query = Sistop::find();
$query->addSelect(['([[qdsistop]] - [[qusistop]]) AS [[diff]]']);

// more examples:
$query->addSelect(['SUM(amount) AS total_annual', 'IF(val > 0, 1, 0) AS is_selected']);
$query->addSelect(['DATE_FORMAT(date_created,'%Y-%m') AS yymm']);
$query->andWhere("[[diff]] >= :limit", [':limit' => 100]);
$query->addGroupBy(['is_selected', 'yymm']);
$query->orderBy(['diff' => SORT_DESC])
```

See the [Yii2 guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#querying-data).